# Make Windows Git Bash terminal look to a custom location for .bashrc & .bash_profile

Tags: windows, git-bash, bash

On Windows I have installed Git Bash. My `HOMEPATH` & `HOMEDRIVE` environment variables are set so that my home directory is `M:\`.  As of now I have my `.bashrc` & `.bash_profile` files sitting at `M:\` & they work just fine.

My question: Is there a way to have Git Bash look somewhere other than `M:\` for `.bashrc` & `.bash_profile` without changing my `HOMEPATH` & `HOMEDRIVE` environment variables?

For example, I want to keep my system's home directory at `M:\` but move `.bashrc` & `.bash_profile` to `C:\my\new\location`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `.bash*` files are referenced by `HOME`, so simply set (create) the `HOME` environment variable to `C:\my\new\location`

Then open a bash session and check that your resource files are sourced.

`HOMEPATH` and `HOMEDRIVE` will be unchanged.